# Javascript load images in canvas with JCanvaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, canvas, html5-canvas

I am using JcanvaScript library to work with Html5 canvas and now I want to load some images in my Canvas, but only last image loading is successful, I can't see any other images but the last one and I don't know what is wrong with my code.

here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      canvas {
           border: 1px solid #9C9898;
       }
    </style>
      <script src="jcanvas/jCanvaScript.1.5.15.js"></script>
      <script>
          var imagesUrl = [];
          var imagesObj = [];
          var canvasWidth = 800;
          var canvasHeight = 600;
          var imagesIdPrefix = 'images_';
          var canvas = "canvas";
          var fps = 60;

          imagesUrl.push('images/image1.jpg');
          imagesUrl.push('images/image2.jpg');
          imagesUrl.push('images/image3.jpg');
          imagesUrl.push('images/image4.jpg');

          function init(){
              for (i = 0; i < imagesUrl.length; i++){
                  var xImage = new Image();
                  xImage.src = imagesUrl[i];
                  xImage.onload = function(){
                      jc.start(canvas, fps);
                      jc.image(xImage, i*10, 0, 200, 200)
                              .id(imagesIdPrefix.toString() + i.toString());
                      jc.start(canvas, fps);
                  }
                  imagesObj.push(xImage);
              }
          }

      </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="init()">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="800px" height="600px"></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are using your iterator variable in your callback function, so the value of `i` in the `onload` function will always be the same. Also, your `i` variable is global; you should add `var` in front of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bug has been identified in comment by MrOBrian : when the onload callbacks are called, i has the value it has at the end of the loop. That's the reason why you think that only last image loading is successful.

A standard solution is to embbed the content of the loop in a closure keeping the value of i  :

```
for (i = 0; i < imagesUrl.length; i++){
     (function(i){
              var xImage = new Image();
              xImage.src = imagesUrl[i];
              xImage.onload = function(){
                  jc.start(canvas, fps);
                  jc.image(xImage, i*10, 0, 200, 200)
                          .id(imagesIdPrefix.toString() + i.toString());
                  jc.start(canvas, fps);
              }
              imagesObj.push(xImage);
       })(i);
   }
```

**EDIT :**

when you want to ensure all the needed images are loaded before running some code, you may use this function :

```
function onLoadAll(images, callback) {
    var n=0;
    for (var i=images.length; i-->0;) {
        if (images[i].width==0) {
            n++;
            images[i].onload=function(){
                if (--n==0) callback();
            };
        }
    }
    if (n==0) callback();
}
```

The images must have been provided their src first. You call the function like this :

```
onLoadAll(imagesObj, function(){
     // do something with imagesObj
});
```

Comment: Another problem eraised with your code, all images load fine but with out order. do you know what is wrong?

Comment: The loading order doesn't have to be the one of the initialization, as it depends on the network. If you want I can propose you a function which calls your code only when all images are loaded.

Comment: wow it works, I added all canvas drow functions inside onLoadAll callback and everything works fine. Thank you very much!!!!!! :)

Comment: You're welcome. It's always a pleasure to learn one has been useful :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure the images are loaded before you go and loop through them.

By defining your `onload` function inside of the `for` loop, the image may not have loaded by that point, and so the script will skip over it. And when it's done looping, the last image may be the only one that's loaded in time.

I would recommend adding a loader for each of the images **outside** the `for` loop, and when all the images are loaded go ahead and loop through the array.

A loader and checker looks something like this:

```
var loadedImages = [];
var loadedNumber = 3 //the number of images you need loaded    
var imageToBeLoaded = new Image();
imageToBeLoaded.onload = function() {
    loadedImages.push(true);
    checkImages();
}
function checkImages() {
    if (loadedImages.length != loadedNumber) {
        setTimeout(checkImages(),1000);
    } else {
        init(); //your draw function
    }
}
```