# Asynchronicity issue when reading files

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cordova

So, I have the following code:

```
function sortVitalsByDate(tx, results){
vitals_counter = 0;
showLoader();
if(results.rows.length > 0){
    for (var i=0;i<results.rows.length;i++){
        vitals_counter += 1;
        var record_id = results.rows.item(i).id;
        readData('clinicalObservation', record_id, populateVitalsDateList);//calls readData function, uses populateVitalsDateList as the success callback (below)
        //hideVitalsLoader();
    }
    console.log("< === sqlHostingArray == "+ sqlHostingArray); //sqlHostingArray is blank
}else{
    $("#vitals-measures-content").html('<div class="no-info">No Information Entered</div>');
    hideVitalsLoader();
}
console.log(arguments.callee.name + ", # rows: " + results.rows.length);
}

function populateVitalsDateList(tx, results){
var listItems = ""; 
for (var i=0;i<results.rows.length;i++){
    var data_element = results.rows.item(i).data_element;
    var heading;
    var label;
    var listItem;
    var value;
    var bpsVal;

    switch(data_element){
    case 'clinicalObservationDate': 
        label = null;
        value = null;
        listItem = null;
        var dateObj = new Date(parseInt(results.rows.item(i).field_value,10));
        //console.log("< == dateObj is " + results.rows.item(i).field_value);
        //heading = formatDate(dateObj);
        // v1.1.1 CRM date sorage callback
        storeDateTemporarily(dateObj);

        heading = decrypt(results.rows.item(i).field_label);
        sqlHostingArray.push(heading);
        break;  
    case 'bloodPressureSystolic':   
        label = "Blood Pressure";
        value = decrypt(results.rows.item(i).field_value);
        bpsVal = value;
        break;   

    case 'bloodPressureDiastolic':
        label = "Blood Pressure";
        value = decrypt(results.rows.item(i).field_value);
        if (value != "" && value != null && value != undefined){
            listItem = addDateLI(results.rows.item(i).record_id, label, bpsVal + "/" + value);
        }else{
            listItem = "";
        }
        break;

    case 'pulse':
        label = "Pulse";
        value = decrypt(results.rows.item(i).field_value);          
        if (value != "" && value != null && value != undefined){
            listItem = addDateLI(results.rows.item(i).record_id, label, value + " bpm");
        }else{
            listItem = "";
        }           
        break;
    case 'respRateValue':
        label = "Respiratory Rate";
        value = decrypt(results.rows.item(i).field_value);
        if (value != "" && value != null && value != undefined){
            listItem = addDateLI(results.rows.item(i).record_id, label, value + " bpm");
        }else{
            listItem = "";
        }
        break;
    case 'heightValue1':
        label = "Height";
        value = decrypt(results.rows.item(i).field_value);
        if (value != "" && value != null && value != undefined){
            listItem = addDateLI(results.rows.item(i).record_id, label, value + " cm");
        }else{
            listItem = "";
        }
        break;
    case 'weightValue':
        label = "Weight";
        value = decrypt(results.rows.item(i).field_value);
        if (value != "" && value != null && value != undefined){
            listItem = addDateLI(results.rows.item(i).record_id, label, value + " kg");
        }else{
            listItem = "";
        }
        break;
    case 'bmi':
        label = "BMI";
        value = decrypt(results.rows.item(i).field_value);
        if (value != "" && value != null && value != undefined){
            listItem = addDateLI(results.rows.item(i).record_id, label, value);
        }else{
            listItem = "";
        } 
        break;
    case 'tempBody':
        label = "Temperature";
        value = decrypt(results.rows.item(i).field_value);
        if (value != "" && value != null && value != undefined){
            listItem = addDateLI(results.rows.item(i).record_id, label, value + " &deg;C");
        }else{
            listItem = "";
        } 
        break;
    default:
        label = null; 
        listItem = null;
        break;        

    }

    if (label != null && label != "" && label != undefined && listItem != null && listItem != "" && listItem != undefined){
        listItems += listItem;
    }
    //console.log(arguments.callee.name + ", label: " + label + ", listItem: " + listItem + ", data_element: " + data_element);
    vitals_counter -= 1;
    hideVitalsLoader();
}
}
```

This all works perfectly fine, except that the line `console.log("< === sqlHostingArray == " + sqlHostingArray);` tells me that the console.log is being called before the for loop directly above it completes. Meaning, the variables being pushed to the `sqlHostingArray` are not defined at the point I need to use them, even though it should execute after. It works fine if the variable is called inside the loop, but I absolutely have to have it execute after the loop has finished. Does anyone know of a way to fix it?

**EDIT**

Ok, so it executes asynchronously.... How do I keep the part I need to execute **after** the for loop, to wait until the loop has finished.

Comment: Just so you know, the noun form is [**asynchrony**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchrony).

Comment: Too many times this question has been asked today. There should be a banner on SO just for this.

Comment: we need a good xkcd comic for "ajax is asynchronous"

Comment: @dystroy Aside from the typographical issue in the title, and the fact that it executes asynchrony, does anyone have a way to keep the part after the for loop from executing until the for loop has completed?

Comment: You have to put this second part of the code in a callback that you'll call after the distant reading has finished. I'm looking for a duplicate which will explain better.

Comment: This is a kind of duplicate, maybe it will help get the logic of the callback solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12090996/waiting-for-a-file-to-load-onload-javascript/12091013#12091013

Comment: @dystroy Well, that's somewhat helpful, but I have to make sure that where the console.log is (there will be different code there eventually) only executes once, if i have a callback inside a for-loop, then I have it executing each iteration of said loop.

Comment: The simplest solution is to have a count of the files you still need to download and test it in your callback. Something like the function I propose in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12056849/javascript-load-images-in-canvas-with-jcanvascript/12059157#12059157). Keep in mind that you must get this asynchronicity/event/callback logic in order to design your web app.

Comment: This is too much code. You should be reducing your code to a [short, self-contained correct example](http://sscce.org/) before posting, rather than relying on us to dredge through 200 lines of JavaScript. This is not a free debugging service.